# Model.train( ) returns automatically in YOLO v8

Tags: object-detection, transfer-learning, yolo

I'm trying to find the best sets of hyperparameters for my YOLO V8 model on my custom dataset with RayTune. I wanted to train the model with **model.train()** and return some of the evaluation metrics, such as mAP50 (for demonstration purposes, I write 'acc' in my code below). Whenever I call the **model_train()** function from **tune.run()**, the model_train() is being returned by the model.train() itself and never reaches the return **{'acc': 0.8}**. How can I save the models' metrics in a variable such as **trained_model = model.train()** and not return from the function automatically? Thank you so much.

```
import YOLO
import os
import ray
from ray import tune
from ray.tune.schedulers import ASHAScheduler
from ray.tune.suggest.hyperopt import HyperOptSearch

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
data = './data.yaml'

def model_train(config):
    trained_model = model.train(    data=data, 
                            batch=16, 
                            epochs=2, 
                            workers=8, 
                            imgsz=640, 
                            patience=1, 
                            save=False, 
                            )
                            
    return {'acc': 0.8}


ray.init()

# Define the search space for hyperparameters
search_space = {
    "learning_rate": tune.loguniform(1e-4, 1e-1),
    "batch_size": tune.choice([8, 16, 32]),
    "num_layers": tune.choice([3, 4, 5]),
    # Add other hyperparameters for YOLOv7
    # ...
}

# Define the hyperparameter search algorithm
search_alg = HyperOptSearch(metric="acc", mode="max")

# Define the scheduler
scheduler = ASHAScheduler(max_t=10, grace_period=1)

# Perform hyperparameter tuning
analysis = tune.run(
    model_train,
    config=search_space,
    num_samples=10,  # Number of hyperparameter combinations to try
    search_alg=search_alg,
    scheduler=scheduler
)

# Get the best hyperparameters and evaluation metric
best_hyperparameters = analysis.get_best_config(metric="acc", mode="max")
best_metric = analysis.best_result["acc"]

print("Best hyperparameters:", best_hyperparameters)
print("Best evaluation metric:", best_metric)

# Clean up Ray resources
ray.shutdown()
```